# Saying tachanun when the tzibbur doesn't

Tags: halacha, tzibur-community, tachanun

If one is davening at a minyan where they don't say tachanun, for reasons that the individual does not feel tachanun should be skipped for, should they say tachanun or skip it?  If they should say it, should they leave the room to do so or should they say it in place?  Is there any way to permit the person to say it later?

Comment: ta7anun can be said whenever a person wants with or without a 9ibbur and how many times he wants in a day

Comment: I always leave the room or "fake it". I've seen this done by Talmidei Chachamim as well.

Comment: @Yehoshua how do you "fake" _not_ saying tachanun?

Comment: If you go ahead and say Tachanun before the repetition it doesn't stand out that much because people aren't expecting it, and you aren't sitting during Kaddish.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked this question to Reb Dovid Feinstein with respect to a Chassidish shul that skips Tachanun on various days when I don't, and he said I could ignore that custom and say Tachanun there.

Answer (score 3):

Halichos Shlomo (rulings of R' Shlomo Zalman Aurebach) Tefillah (13:5) rules that if the tzibbur omit *tachanun*, one should exit the shul and recite *tachanun*, unless it is omitted due to a *minhag* of the Shul.

[image]

This is distinction is explained in the footnotes. Rule of the thumb is: Any time *tachanun* is omitted due to a minhag - like some Chassidim not reciting *tachanun* by Mincha, or on the Yortzeit of a tzaddik - then one should not recite *tachnan* against the *minhag hamakom*. Since the ideal time of *tachanun* [immediately after *chazaras hashatz*] has passed, one doesn't need to recite afterwards.

[image]
[image]

Ishei Yisrael (Perek 25, fn 46) quotes this ruling from R' Shlomo Zalman Aurebach, but follows with a ruling from R' Chaim Kanievsky that one should recite *tachanun* afterwards. Seemingly, R' Chaim agreed that one should not do so publicly, but is required to follow up afterwards.

[image]

Similarly, Rivevos Ephraim (Vol 7, Siman 395, 2:3)  was asked whether to say *tachanun* in a locale where it is omitted, at the risk of causing *machlokes*. He responded that if it is based upon the minhag of omitting on Yortzeit, it isn't worth causing *machlokes* and one should either avoid praying in such a shul, or leave and recite afterwards. He concludes that the key is to use common sense.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [dinonline.org](http://dinonline.org/2017/05/17/tachanun-issues/):

> If the reason the tzibbur is not saying tachanun is because of a minhag not brought in halacha, such as not saying tachanun when there is a yahrtziet of a tzaddik, **a person that wants to say tachanun may do so inside the shul.**
>
> If he is in a minyan that regularly doesn’t say tachanun by mincha, he should do like them. The reason for this is that it is considered a minhag done with a halachic basis, since we don’t say tachanun at night and there are places that used to daven close to night time, and in order not to say tachanun at night they don’t say it at all by mincha.

Comment: "we don’t say tachanun at night" How is that a "halachic basis"? Halachically one can say Tachanun even after Maariv, it's just generally omitted because Maariv is entirely a Reshut anyway. It's only extra Halakhic concerns (eg. Kabbalah [apparently]) which recommend against saying Tachanun at night, which should be no different that Yahrtzeit customs or whatever.

Comment: I'm just quoting. Do you suggest i remove the last paragraph from the answer?

Comment: @DoubleAA http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tachanun,_Ashrei,_Aleinu,_Shir_Shel_Yom#Night_time apparently some take it as a halacha.

Comment: Because it's on "halachi"pedia? Lol

Comment: @DoubleAA :) i tried finding a link to yalkut yosef who is quoted there, but it wasn't showing up in sefaria under the source provided.